# Configuring apache solr online

Tags: solr

I want to use Apache-Solr for indexing and searching in my java application. But I don't know how to configure it online. I can copy my solr directory in the root folder,but I don't know where to copy the directory containing solrconfig file,core etc. Hoping to get a solution. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep the config files and core directories in the same directory structure. Just beware, where you store index files (configured in dataDir parameter of solrconfig.xml) so that they don't overrun your disk capacity.

Comment: I tried putting my config files in solr.war but it gives me an error saying, SEVERE: Unable to create core: collection1.

Comment: @user2522497 why do you want to put the config files into war? The solr core is trying to read the files from the file system, not a war package. The good enough approach is put the config files into conf directory on the same level as your webapps directory. This is what I meant by "the same directory structure".